# Manipulating multiple arrays to output a table of unique values

Tags: php, html, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have 5 different arrays which I need to use to generate a table showing the info. This table cannot have duplicates. This is in a way a fairly easy task, but what I am looking for is the most elegant solution - one that doesn't require lots of for loops, array merging etc etc.

The table needs to output information for photo printing. And should look a bit like this:

[image: Example output]

Not like this:

[image]

The arrays look like this:

```
//img arr:
        $img_arr = array(array('002_chrysanthemum', '6x4'), array('002_chrysanthemum', '9x6'));

//size arr:
    $size_arr = array('6x4', '9x6');

//finish arr:
    $finish_arr = array('glossy', 'glossy');

//qty arr:
    $qty_arr = array(2, 3);

//media arr:
    $media_arr = array('std', 'std');
```

Thanks.

*EDIT* - Typo with finish / qty arr pointed out, changed, thanks.

Comment: Should the second `$finish_arr` be `$qty_arr`? Are the comments above each assignment really useful, since they just restate the name of the array (except for that typo)?

Comment: Do you mean `//qty arr:
    $qty_arr` ? Otherwise you overwrite the earlier finish array

Comment: That's the same typo I pointed out.

Comment: Why is `6x4` in both `$img_arr` and `$size_arr`? Which one should be used in the table?

Comment: Please show what you've tried, and explain the problem you're having with it. Also, it would help if you showed a more complete example, not just one row. It's hard to understand what the general case is supposed to be like from what you've posted.

Comment: My guess is that the sizes are meant to corelate the img array to act as  foreign keys. Clearly this approach is less "complicated" and doesn't need some fancy merges.

Comment: Yes Anthony is right. The problem I am having is illustrated in the images provided. It is outputting two rows for one image. I need to output it in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Group your images into an array indexed first by image name and second by its size.
Loop through each size to render the column headers, then loop through each grouped image to render the rows.

```
$img_arr = array(array('002_chrysanthemum', '6x4'), array('002_chrysanthemum', '9x6'));
$size_arr = array('6x4', '9x6');
$finish_arr = array('glossy', 'glossy');
$qty_arr = array(2, 3);
$media_arr = array('std', 'std');
$images = array();

foreach($img_arr as $key => $img) {
    $images[$img[0]][$img[1]] = array(
        'finish' => $finish_arr[$key],
        'qty' => $qty_arr[$key],
        'media' => $media_arr[$key],
    );
}

print "<table>";
print "<tr><th></th>";

foreach($size_arr as $size) {
    print "<th>$size</th>";
}

print "</tr>";

foreach($images as $name => $image) {
    print "<tr><td>$name</td>";        

    foreach($size_arr as $size) {
        print "<td>" . $image[$size]['qty'] 
        . '@' . $image[$size]['finish']
        . ' ' . $image[$size]['media'] . "</td>";          
    }

    print "</tr>";
}

print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$img_arr = array('002_chrysanthemum', '002_chrysanthemum');

$size_arr = array('6x4', '9x6');

$finish_arr = array('glossy', 'glossy');

$qty_arr = array(2, 3);

$media_arr = array('std', 'std');
```

Could be combined into one sensible array like:

```
foreach($img_arr as $k=>$img) {
    foreach($size_arr as $size) {
         $prints[$img][$size]['finish'] = $finish_arr[$k];
         $prints[$img][$size]['qty'] = $qty_arr[$k];
         $prints[$img][$size]['media'] = $media_arr[$k];
      }
  }
```

The result, which is based on the idea that image array is the x-axis and sizes are the y-axis and all other arrays are properties based on position to the y-axis. So then:

```
 print_r($prints);
```

returns

```
Array (
    [002_chrysanthemum] => Array
        (
            [6x4] => Array
                (
                    [finish] => glossy
                    [qty] => 3
                    [media] => std
                )

            [9x6] => Array
                (
                    [finish] => glossy
                    [qty] => 3
                    [media] => std
                )
        )
)
```

Which is the very elegant and simple data collection that you want to transform into a table, which it can be now that it is normalized.